# Angular 8. How to prevent route reset after a page refresh

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, page-refresh

The route is reset after the page is refreshed
This is the router module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'parameters', component: ParametersDialogComponent },
  { path: 'report1', component: Report1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'report2', component: Report2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Login

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 4, url: '/home')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 4, url: "/home", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
```

Current route is localhost:4200/home

after refreshing I got:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
```

and redirects to login page

How to prevent this?

Comment: Your `AuthGuard` 'fails' and redirects back to `/`

Comment: I suspected it, but I can't trace it to debug. When login or other routing, I see the auth passes guard, but refreshes - no.  The same happens if I enter the path in the address bar

Comment: I switched then canActivate off, it always retutns true. The same result

Comment: Is this in a local environment? Or on a production server?

Comment: this is a local, but the same is on the production server

Comment: @VasilyAsur Have you resolved this issue? If so, how?